# Postgres not using index when index scan is much better option

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, database-indexes

I have a simple query to join two tables that's being really slow. I found out that the query plan does a seq scan on the large table `email_activities` (~10m rows) while I think using indexes doing nested loops will actually be faster.

I rewrote the query using a subquery in an attempt to force the use of index, then noticed something interesting. If you look at the two query plans below, you will see that when I limit the result set of subquery to 43k, query plan does use index on email_activities while setting the limit in subquery to even 44k will cause query plan to use seq scan on `email_activities`. One is clearly more efficient than the other, but Postgres doesn't seem to care.

What could cause this?  Does it have a configs somewhere that forces the use of hash join if one of the set is larger than certain size?

```
explain analyze SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "email_activities"."email_recipient_id") FROM "email_activities" where email_recipient_id in (select "email_recipients"."id" from email_recipients WHERE "email_recipients"."email_campaign_id" = 1607 limit 43000);
                                                                                            QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=118261.50..118261.50 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=224.556..224.556 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3699.03..118147.99 rows=227007 width=4) (actual time=32.586..209.076 rows=40789 loops=1)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3698.94..3827.94 rows=43000 width=4) (actual time=32.572..47.276 rows=43000 loops=1)
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.09..3548.44 rows=43000 width=4) (actual time=0.017..22.547 rows=43000 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using index_email_recipients_on_email_campaign_id on email_recipients  (cost=0.09..5422.47 rows=65710 width=4) (actual time=0.017..19.168 rows=43000 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (email_campaign_id = 1607)
         ->  Index Only Scan using index_email_activities_on_email_recipient_id on email_activities  (cost=0.09..2.64 rows=5 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=43000)
               Index Cond: (email_recipient_id = email_recipients.id)
               Heap Fetches: 40789
 Total runtime: 224.675 ms
```

And:

```
explain analyze SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "email_activities"."email_recipient_id") FROM "email_activities" where email_recipient_id in (select "email_recipients"."id" from email_recipients WHERE "email_recipients"."email_campaign_id" = 1607 limit 50000);
                                                                                            QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=119306.25..119306.25 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=3050.612..3050.613 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=4451.08..119174.27 rows=263962 width=4) (actual time=1831.673..3038.683 rows=47935 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (email_activities.email_recipient_id = email_recipients.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on email_activities  (cost=0.00..107490.96 rows=9359988 width=4) (actual time=0.003..751.988 rows=9360039 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=4276.08..4276.08 rows=50000 width=4) (actual time=34.058..34.058 rows=50000 loops=1)
               Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1758kB
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.09..4126.08 rows=50000 width=4) (actual time=0.016..27.302 rows=50000 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using index_email_recipients_on_email_campaign_id on email_recipients  (cost=0.09..5422.47 rows=65710 width=4) (actual time=0.016..22.244 rows=50000 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (email_campaign_id = 1607)
 Total runtime: 3050.660 ms
```

- Version: PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
- email_activities:  ~10m rows
- email_recipients:  ~11m rows

Comment: The `HashAggregate` operation might require too much memory for 50k rows.  Try to increase [`work_mem`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html) ?

Comment: Basic information is missing. Please consider instructions in the [tag info for \[postgresql-perfiormance\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). Also, your 2nd query is for `LIMIT 50000`, not for `44k` as stated above. Adds to the difference.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, sorry for the confusion.  I was just saying that raising the limit to 44k from 43k does change the plan to seq scan. (went down to 44k from 50k...).  Thanks for the tag info though.  This was first time posting related to postgres for me.

Comment: Does anyone know a clean way of pasting \d+ into a question?

Answer (score 58):

#### Index (Only) Scan --> Bitmap Index Scan --> Sequential Scan

For few rows it pays to run an index scan. If enough data pages are visible to all (= vacuumed enough, and not too much concurrent write load) and the index can provide all column values needed, then a faster index only scan is used. With more rows expected to be returned (higher percentage of the table and depending on data distribution, value frequencies and row width) it becomes more likely to find several rows on one data page. Then it pays to switch to a bitmap index scans. (Or to combine multiple distinct indexes.) Once a large percentage of data pages has to be visited anyway, it's cheaper to run a sequential scan, filter surplus rows and skip the overhead for indexes altogether.

Index usage becomes (much) cheaper and more likely when accessing data pages in random order is not (much) more expensive than accessing them in sequential order. That's the case when using SSD instead of spinning disks, or even more so the more is cached in RAM - and the respective configuration parameters [`random_page_cost`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-RANDOM-PAGE-COST) and [`effective_cache_size`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-EFFECTIVE-CACHE-SIZE) are set accordingly.

In your case, Postgres switches to a sequential scan, expecting to find `rows=263962`, that's already 3 % of the whole table. (While only `rows=47935` are actually found, see below.)

More in this related answer:

- [Efficient PostgreSQL query on timestamp using index or bitmap index scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759003/efficient-postgresql-query-with-date-arithmetic/24760433#24760433)

### Beware of forcing query plans

You cannot force a certain planner method directly in Postgres, but you can make *other* methods seem extremely expensive for debugging purposes. See [Planner Method Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) in the manual.

`SET enable_seqscan = off` (like suggested in another answer) does that to sequential scans. But that's intended for debugging purposes in your session only. Do ***not*** use this as a general setting in production unless you know exactly what you are doing. It can force ridiculous query plans. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE):

> These configuration parameters provide a crude method of influencing
> the query plans chosen by the query optimizer. If the default plan
> chosen by the optimizer for a particular query is not optimal, a
> *temporary* solution is to use one of these configuration parameters to force the optimizer to choose a different plan. Better ways to
> improve the quality of the plans chosen by the optimizer include
> adjusting the planner cost constants (see [Section 19.7.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS)),
> running [`ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) manually, increasing the value of the
> [`default_statistics_target`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET) configuration parameter, and
> increasing the amount of statistics collected for specific columns
> using `ALTER TABLE SET STATISTICS`.

That's already most of the advice you need.

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

In this particular case, Postgres expects 5-6 times more hits on `email_activities.email_recipient_id` than are actually found:

> estimated `rows=227007` vs. `actual ... rows=40789`
> estimated `rows=263962` vs. `actual ... rows=47935`

If you run this query often it will pay to have `ANALYZE` look at a bigger sample for more accurate statistics on the particular column. Your table is big (~ 10M rows), so make that:

```
ALTER TABLE email_activities ALTER COLUMN email_recipient_id
SET STATISTICS 3000;  -- max 10000, default 100
```

Then `ANALYZE email_activities;`

#### Measure of last resort

In *very rare* cases you might resort to force an index with `SET LOCAL enable_seqscan = off` in a separate transaction or in a function with its own environment. Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_count_dist_recipients(_email_campaign_id int, _limit int)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.email_recipient_id)
   FROM   email_activities a
   WHERE  a.email_recipient_id IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM   email_recipients
      WHERE  email_campaign_id = $1
      LIMIT  $2)       -- or consider query below
$func$  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE COST 100000 SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

The setting only applies to the local scope of the function.

**Warning:** This is just a proof of concept. Even this much less radical manual intervention might bite you in the long run. Cardinalities, value frequencies, your schema, global Postgres settings, everything changes over time. You are going to upgrade to a new Postgres version. The query plan you force now, may become a very bad idea later.

And typically this is just a workaround for a problem with your setup. Better find and fix it.

#### Alternative query

Essential information is missing in the question, but this equivalent query is probably faster and more likely to use an index on (`email_recipient_id`) - increasingly so for a bigger `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT id
   FROM   email_recipients
   WHERE  email_campaign_id = 1607
   LIMIT  43000
   ) r
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM email_activities
   WHERE  email_recipient_id = r.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer.

Comment: Great answer, but it didn't work for me. Apparently I had to terminate some idle connections, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364828/1513222)

Comment: Great answer. Helped us understand why Seq Scan was being performed.

Answer (score 5):

A sequential scan can be more efficient, even when an index exists. In this case, postgres seems to estimate things rather wrong.
An `ANALYZE <TABLE>` on all related tables can help in such cases. If it doesnt, you can set the variable `enable_seqscan` to OFF, to force postgres to use an index whenever technically possible, at the expense, that sometimes an index-scan will be used when a sequential scan would perform better.

Comment: Agree with analyze but i really wouldn't recommend to set enable_seqscan to OFF. can cause slow in other queries

Comment: I've run into this with Postgresql.  For me, the best results seemed to come from partitioning the data within the table, which really seems to force it to use a more reasonable set even when it ends up doing a scan.

Comment: A really useful option if you want to make sure the query is actually using the index, but shouldn't be used in a production environment.