# Postgres, Simple Queries not using index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

PostgreSQL 9.5.0

I have a table called `message_attachments` it has `1931964` rows.

There's one key that I search for in that table, that's `message_id`.

I also, always include the `deleted_at` is NULL statement (e.g. soft delete).

There was an index created:

```
CREATE INDEX message_attachments_message_id_idx 
   ON message_attachments (message_id) 
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

So it should directly match this query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
select * 
from "message_attachments" 
where "deleted_at" is null 
  and "message_id" = 33998052;
```

But the resulting query plan looks like this:

```
Seq Scan on message_attachments  (cost=0.00..69239.91 rows=4 width=149) (actual time=1667.850..1667.850 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (message_id = 33998052))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1931896
 Planning time: 0.114 ms
 Execution time: 1667.885 ms
```

I'm using such indices through out my database, but somehow it seems that it doesn't like it on that specific table.

Regarding cardinality, there's at most 5 columns with the same value.

Also a ANALYZE and VACUUM ANALYZE was run on that table.

**Edit 1**

`SET enable_seqscan to off`

```
SET enable_seqscan to off; EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from "message_attachments" where "deleted_at" is null and "message_id" = 33998052;
SET
                                                                           QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on message_attachments  (cost=36111.83..105378.49 rows=4 width=149) (actual time=2343.361..2343.361 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (deleted_at IS NULL)
   Filter: (message_id = 33998052)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1932233
   Heap Blocks: exact=45086
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on message_attachments_deleted_at_index  (cost=0.00..36111.82 rows=1934453 width=0) (actual time=789.836..789.836 rows=1933784 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (deleted_at IS NULL)
 Planning time: 0.098 ms
 Execution time: 2343.425 ms
```

This would be running now on the second index on that table, which looks like that: (and should definitely NOT be used)

```
CREATE INDEX message_attachments_deleted_at_index ON message_attachments USING btree (deleted_at)
```

**Edit 2**

```
\d+ message_attachments
                                                         Table "public.message_attachments"
   Column   |            Type             |                            Modifiers                             | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('message_attachments_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null                                                         | plain    |              |
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null                                                         | plain    |              |
 deleted_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                                  | plain    |              |
 name       | character varying(255)      | not null                                                         | extended |              |
 filename   | character varying(255)      | not null                                                         | extended |              |
 content    | bytea                       |                                                                  | extended |              |
 hash       | character varying(255)      | not null                                                         | extended |              |
 mime       | character varying(255)      | not null                                                         | extended |              |
 size       | bigint                      | not null                                                         | plain    |              |
 message_id | bigint                      | not null                                                         | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "message_attachments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "message_attachments_deleted_at_index" btree (deleted_at)
    "message_attachments_message_id_idx" btree (message_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
Foreign-key constraints:
    "message_attachments_message_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (message_id) REFERENCES messages(id)
```

**Edit3**

Exactly the same behaviour on a hot standby host. (it is up2date)

**Edit4**

```
select seq_scan,seq_tup_read,idx_scan,idx_tup_fetch,n_live_tup,pg_stat_all_tables.n_dead_tup,last_analyze,pg_stat_all_tables.analyze_count,pg_stat_all_tables.last_autoanalyze from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'message_attachments';
 seq_scan |  seq_tup_read  | idx_scan | idx_tup_fetch | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup |         last_analyze          | analyze_count |       last_autoanalyze
----------+----------------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------
 18728036 | 26379554229720 |  1475541 |     808566894 |    1934435 |      28052 | 2017-04-12 09:48:34.638184+02 |            68 | 2017-02-02 18:41:05.902214+01

select * from pg_stat_all_indexes where relname = 'message_attachments';
 relid  | indexrelid | schemaname |       relname       |             indexrelname             | idx_scan | idx_tup_read | idx_tup_fetch
--------+------------+------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------------
 113645 |     113652 | public     | message_attachments | message_attachments_pkey             |  1475563 |    804751648 |     802770401
 113645 |     113659 | public     | message_attachments | message_attachments_deleted_at_index |        3 |      5801165 |             0
 113645 |   20954507 | public     | message_attachments | message_attachments_message_id_idx   |        0 |            0 |             0
```

Comment: try `SET enable_seqscan to off` and run analyze again to check the costs

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? Are you really sure you analyzed the table? The fact that Postgres estimates only 4 rows (when the table has nearly 2 million) seems to indicate that the statistics are **not** up-to-date.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that definitly is weird! I'm using 9.5, and within pg_class it tells me there are 1934020 tuples, where does the estimate for the 4 rows come from? And I did definitly run VACUUM ANALYZE message_attachments, and ANALYZE message_attachments

Comment: @VaoTsun added the query plan with seqscan of, for me it looks like it doesn't see the index at all!

Comment: hm. out of curiosity - could first inde be unusable?.. please add `\d+ message_attachments` for full picture

Comment: @VaoTsun added full output to post

Comment: Does `reindex index message_attachments_message_id_idx` change anything? (Also: you should really upgrade to the latest 9.5 patch version which is 9.5.6)

Comment: okay will try todo that today in the evening, reindex changes nothing!

Is there somewhere a known bug?!

Comment: added a comment about standby

Comment: please also update question with output for `select seq_scan,seq_tup_read,idx_scan,idx_tup_fetch,n_live_tup,n_dead_tup,last_analyze,last_autoanalyze,analyze_count,autoanalyze_count from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'message_attachments';` to avoid doubts

Comment: and `select * from pg_stat_all_indexes where relname = 'message_attachments';`

Comment: @VaoTsun both added

Comment: @VaoTsun it was a open sharedLock from days ago, I feel stupid, but I would hope that Postgres could tell me that ...

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I just solved this.

We had somehow a hanging LOCK for a query that was killed in php, but never exited the process on postgres from a few days ago.

So, for everyone expiriencing the same issues, check you LOCKS:

```
SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT GRANTED;
```

And also, if there are any connections open since a few days ago:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity order by query_start limit 10;
```

Comment: I was just about to ask if you had any "idle in transaction" sessions...

Comment: you had a lock on index, not a table? and you could rebuild that index, but not use for select?..

Comment: no, the lock was on a COMPLETELY (INSERT INTO customers) different table, it wasn't even active, it was waiting to be granted.

And no newly created index was used ANYWHERE in the database.

Comment: I'm so confused it looks like explanation to you :) I don't understand it - how that lock can influence execution plan?..

Comment: don't ask me, otherwise I wouldn't have opened that question :D

For me it looks like the issue was that the planner was hanging at a certain xact (not sure if it works like that), so that all indices, that didn't exist at that xact (from a few days ago) were simply ignored.

Comment: Had the same nasty behaviour. Indeed, I could finally make the planner see the index by disconnecing an old session from a user. Thanks.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. Killing some locked queries made the index immediately visible. Thanks!