# Optimising function which extracts records with a minimum gap in timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a big table of timestamps in Postgres 9.4.5:

```
CREATE TABLE vessel_position (
  posid serial NOT NULL,
  mmsi integer NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamp with time zone,
  the_geom geometry(PointZ,4326),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_posid_mmsi" PRIMARY KEY (posid, mmsi)
);
```

Additional index:

```
CREATE INDEX vessel_position_timestamp_idx ON vessel_position ("timestamp");
```

I want to extract every row where the timestamp is at least x minutes after the previous row. I've tried a few different `SELECT` statements using `LAG()` which all kind of worked, but didn't give me the exact result I require. The below functions gives me what I need, but I feel it could be quicker:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _getVesslTrackWithInterval(mmsi integer, startTime character varying (25) ,endTime character varying (25), interval_min integer)
RETURNS SETOF vessel_position AS
$func$
DECLARE
    count integer DEFAULT 0;
    posids varchar DEFAULT '';
    tbl CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
      posID
      ,EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp -  lag(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY posid asc)))::int as diff
    FROM vessel_position vp WHERE vp.mmsi = $1  AND vp.timestamp BETWEEN $2::timestamp AND $3::timestamp;
BEGIN
FOR row IN tbl
LOOP
    count := coalesce(row.diff,0) + count;
    IF count >= $4*60 OR count = 0 THEN
            posids:= posids || row.posid || ',';
            count:= 0;
     END IF;
END LOOP;
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * from vessel_position where posid in (' || TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM posids) || ')';
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I can't help thinking getting all the `posids` as a string and then selecting them all again at the very end is slowing things down.
Within the `IF` statement, I already have access to each row I want to keep, so could potentially store them in a temp table and then return temp table at the end of the loop.

Can this function be optimised - to improve performance in particular?

Comment: [About the outdated Postgres version 9.4.5](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): `We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Query

Your function has all kinds of expensive, unnecessary overhead. A single query should be ***many times faster***, doing the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _get_vessel_track_with_interval
 (mmsi int, starttime timestamptz, endtime timestamptz, min_interval interval)
  RETURNS SETOF vessel_position AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT (vp).*  -- parentheses required for decomposing row type
   FROM  (
      SELECT vp   -- whole row (!)
           , timestamp - lag(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY posid) AS diff
      FROM   vessel_position vp
      WHERE  vp.mmsi = $1
      AND    vp.timestamp >= $2     -- typically you'd include the lower bound
      AND    vp.timestamp <  $3;    -- ... and exlude the upper
      ORDER  BY posid
      ) sub
   WHERE  diff >= $4;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Could also just be an SQL function or the bare `SELECT` without any wrapper (Maybe as prepared statement? [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018991/split-given-string-and-prepare-case-statement/28220532#28220532))

Note how `starttime` and `endtime` are  passed as `timestamp`. (Makes no sense to pass as `text` and cast.) And the minimum interval `min_interval` is an actual [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). Pass *any* interval of your choosing.

#### Index

If the predicate on `mmsi` is in any way selective, the two indexes you currently *have* (PK ON `(posid, mmsi)` and idx on `(timestamp)`) are not very useful. If you reverse the column order of your PK to `(mmsi, posid)`, it becomes far more useful for the query at hand. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

The optimal index for this would typically be on `vessel_position(mmsi, timestamp)`. Related:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684)
- [PostgreSQL performance with (col = value or col is NULL)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/226453/3684)
- [Query does not hit the index - are these the proper columns to index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158884/query-does-not-hit-the-index-are-these-the-proper-columns-to-index/56160596#56160596)

Aside: Avoid [keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers. That's asking for trouble. Plus, a column `timestamp` that actually holds `timestamptz` is misleading.

Comment: @wildplasser: nope :) I select *the whole row* in the subquery, and decompose it in the outer `SELECT` to match the return type declared as `SETOF vessel_position` without spelling out all columns. (To get rid of the column `diff` added to the row in the subquery.)

Comment: I see. (kind of)  The `sub` is only  syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it does answer the question I initially asked (happy to accept it as answered), but I realised I missed out one small, but important detail (sorry about that!) which I have now added in the edit above. I have implemented some of your changes i.e passing a timestamp rather than char, and formatting the WHERE differently so hopefully that has sped it up a bit.

Comment: @BStone: I rolled back your edits *changing* the question (but kept the useful additions). You can find everything in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56172750/revisions). I suggest you start a new question for your changed objective. (I might have a couple of ideas.) You can always link to this one for context - and drop a comment here to link back and get my attention.

Comment: Also note the change from `timestamp` -> `timestamptz` after you disclosed the table definition. Else the current time zone setting can change results. It is important to understand implications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860

Comment: I see you did not post your other question. I think I have a solution for that, too.