# Query slows down 5 fold after copying DB (on the same computer!)

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-performance, query-planner

In a location based app,there's a specific query which has to run fast:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users
  WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(40.71427000, -74.00597000), 50000) @> ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)
```

However, when after copying the database by using Postgres' tools:

```
pg_dump dummy_users > dummy_users.dump
createdb slow_db
psql slow_db < dummy_users.dump
```

the query takes 2.5 seconds instead of 0.5 seconds on slow_db!!

The planner chooses a different route in slow_db, eg
Explain analyze on slow_db:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=10825.18..10825.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2164.396..2164.396 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=205.45..10818.39 rows=2714 width=0) (actual time=26.188..2155.680 rows=122836 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ('(1281995.9045467733, -4697354.822067326, 4110397.4955141144),(1381995.648489849, -4597355.078124251, 4210397.23945719)'::cube @> (ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))::cube)"
"        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 364502"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=57514 lossy=33728"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on distance_index  (cost=0.00..204.77 rows=2714 width=0) (actual time=20.068..20.068 rows=122836 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))::cube <@ '(1281995.9045467733, -4697354.822067326, 4110397.4955141144),(1381995.648489849, -4597355.078124251, 4210397.23945719)'::cube)"
"Planning Time: 1.002 ms"
"Execution Time: 2164.807 ms"
```

explain analyze on the origin db:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=8807.01..8807.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=239.524..239.525 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using distance_index on users  (cost=0.41..8801.69 rows=2130 width=0) (actual time=0.156..233.760 rows=122836 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))::cube <@ '(1281995.9045467733, -4697354.822067326, 4110397.4955141144),(1381995.648489849, -4597355.078124251, 4210397.23945719)'::cube)"
"Planning Time: 3.928 ms"
"Execution Time: 239.546 ms"
```

For both tables there's an index on the location which was created in the exact same way:

```
CREATE INDEX 
   distance_index ON users USING gist (ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))
```

I've tried to run maintenance tools (analyze\vaccum etc) before and after running that query, with or without the index, doesn't help!

Both DBS run on the exact same machine (so same postgres server,postgres dist,configuration).
Data on both DBS is the same (one single table), and isn't changing.
The Postgres version = 12.8.

psql's `\l` output for those databases:

```
                              List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------- 
 dummy_users | yoni     | UTF8     | en_IL   | en_IL | 
 slow_db     | yoni     | UTF8     | en_IL   | en_IL |
```

What is going on?

(Thanks to Laurenz Albe) - after
`SET enable_bitmapscan = off;` and `SET enable_seqscan = off;` on the slow database, ran the query again here is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=11018.63..11018.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=213.544..213.545 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=11667 read=110537"
"  ->  Index Scan using distance_index on users  (cost=0.41..11011.86 rows=2711 width=0) (actual time=0.262..207.164 rows=122836 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))::cube <@ '(1282077.0159892815, -4697331.573647572, 4110397.4955141144),(1382076.7599323571, -4597331.829704497, 4210397.23945719)'::cube)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=11667 read=110537"
"Planning Time: 0.940 ms"
"Execution Time: 213.591 ms"
```

Comment: Postgres versions for the database's? Your results are from `EXPLAIN` not `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` as there are no `actual_time` data. Are you sure you ran `ANALYZE` on the new database? If so, what was the actual command?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver PostgreSQL 12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am sure that i ran analyze on the new database, using pgadmin4, right clicked on slow_db -> maintenance and from there I tried everything (analyze, vaccum etc). That being said, I can run the commands manually as well if that could help. Is that the case?

Comment: I do not trust GUI front ends  to do what you use ask.  Use `psql` and connect to the database and run `ANALYZE`.

Comment: Are both databases created with the exact same parameters? If everything on the infrastructure side (PG, machine, etc) is the same, the difference may be on the actual database definition. Try another experiment, dump the `slow_db` table, created a third db slow_db2, restore the table and then run the explain analyze from both slow's if there is no difference it may indicate that the database being created have something different.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver To make sure I am doing things as intended, I will expand on exactly what I did: I ran psql -d slow_db and then just analyze users. Checked again - nothing has changed.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I described exactly how i created it, not too sure about the parameters or how to check them. I've created slow_db2 as per your suggestion, and it is as slow as slow_db. Not sure what that proves though.

Comment: 1) Remove the plain `EXPLAIN` output it just confuses the issue for anyone coming to the question. 2) In `psql` what does `\l` show for the databases in question? *Add as update to question*.

Comment: Can you `SET enable_bitmapscan = off;` and `SET enable_seqscan = off;` on the slow database, run the query again and post the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output you get?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe this made the slow_db query fast as hell. I will post the output you requested in the question's body, I will love to understand things (references are fine), since this is the most important query the DB will do .

Comment: Erwin was faster - I was about to say the same thing.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe okay, notice that after turning back on enable_bitmapscan and enable_seqscan, the critical query timing soared to previous state...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Manual `VACUUM` / `ANALYZE` after restore

After restoring a new database, there are no column statistics yet. Normally, `autovacuum` will kick in eventually, but since *"data [...] isn't changing"*, `autovacuum` wouldn't be triggered.

For the same reason (data isn't changing), I suggest to run this once after restoring your single table:

```
VACUUM (ANALYZE, FREEZE) users;
```

You might as well run `FREEZE` for a table that's never changed.
(`FULL` isn't necessary, since there are no dead tuples in a freshly restored table.)

#### Explanation for the plan change

With everything else being equal, I suspect at least **two** major problems:

1. Bad column statistics
2. Bad database configuration (the more severe problem)

See:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

In the slow DB, Postgres expects `rows=2714`, while it expects `rows=2130` in the fast one. The difference may not seem huge, but may well be enough to tip Postgres over to the other query plan (that turns out to be inferior).

Seeing that Postgres actually finds `rows=122836`, **either estimate is bad**. The one in the slow DB is actually **less bad**. But the bitmap scan turns out to be slower than the index scan, even with many more qualifying rows than expected. (!) So your database configuration is most probably way off. The main problem typically is the default [**`random_page_cost`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-RANDOM-PAGE-COST) of **4**, while a realistic setting for fully cached read-only table is much closer to **1**. Maybe 1.1 to allow for *some* additional cost. There are a couple other settings that encourage index scans. Like [`effective_cache_size`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-EFFECTIVE-CACHE-SIZE). Start here:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Estimates are just that: *estimates*. And column statistics are also just that: *statistics*. So not exact but subject to random variation. You might increase the statistics target to increase the validity of column statistics.

Cheap random reads favor index scans and discourage bitmap index scans.
More qualifying rows favor a bitmap index scan. Less favor an index scan. See:

- [Postgres not using index when index scan is much better option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537096/postgres-not-using-index-when-index-scan-is-much-better-option/34584053#34584053)

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer, however- after turning back on enable_seqscan and  enable_bitmapscan, and after running VACUUM (ANALYZE, FREEZE) users, the critical query timing timing went back to 2.5 seconds.

Comment: @yonikeren: Did you also tune the database configuration like suggested?

Comment: Sorry, after set random_page_cost=1.1; the timing went down to 0.5s which is alright.

Comment: My concern is that at production the table will change for sure (so the random page cost at 1.1 might not be ideal).  Knowing ahead of time that index scan will be better than any other scan, is it actually okay to force postgres's hand down and  SET enable_bitmapscan = off etc. even though it is "ugly"?

Comment: @yonikeren: I would not go there. Too ugly. And typically not necessary. The default setting of *4.0* for `random_page_cost` is only appropriate for infrequently used databases or a serious lack of RAM in combination with anachronistically slow storage, so basically never nowadays. Writes to the table are only a secondary factor. As long as your table can typically remain cached, *1.0* is the realistic setting. *1.1* for *some* leeway.

Comment: BTW, `Buffers: shared hit=11667 read=110537` means you ran the query on mostly cold cache. Repeated calls should get *much* faster, yet, with warm cache - assuming reasonable RAM and settings.